# Highcharts/Highstock flags series issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

Why aren't ALL the flags in the withdrawals series showing? Please see the following JS fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/lucianpurcarea/5zxa0jsm/13/

This is the part that creates the data array for the withdrawals series:

```
var withdrawalsFlags = [];
for (var w = 0; w < response.withdrawals.length; w++) {
  var title = "W:" + response.withdrawals[w][1] + "$";
  withdrawalsFlags.push({
    "x": response.withdrawals[w][0],
    "id": (response.withdrawals[w][0]),
    "title": title
  });
}
```

In the fiddle that i prepared, the "title" on the withdrawals series is made up of "W: " + *dollar value* + "$". When this is the case, i see about 5 flags on the series. If i remove the "W:" i see more, if i remove the "$" at the end as well i see them all.

If i zoom in on one specific section, i see all the flags present in that section.

Thanks in advance to anyone taking a look at this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All flags are not presented because in Highcharts `flags` type series has property [allowOverlapX](https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series.flags.allowOverlapX) set to `false` by default.

Highcharts documentation:

> If false, the flags are moved sideways using an algorithm that seeks
>   to place every flag as close as possible to its original position.

Set `allowOverlapX = true` and you will see all your flags.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/509anv32/1/